# Gmail Atom feed for priority messages in my inbox

Tags: gmail, priority-inbox

I'm trying to configure a desktop application that uses Gmail's atom feed, which looks at urls of the form

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/<label>
```

It works *great* for `all`, and `inbox`, but unfortunately not so well when I set it to `important`: in the last case it will look for every unread message that's been labeled as `important` which unfortunately includes a lot of messages which don't make my inbox.

I'm looking for a workaround that makes the atom feed list only `important` messages that are *also* in my inbox. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another label filter for mails which are important and in inbox and use that label.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's been a long time, but I want to post a solution here for people in the future.

Instead of the `important` label, you should use `^iim`. [https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/^iim](https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/%5Eiim)

This will show a list of emails in your inbox that are unread and marked as important. I have "priority inbox" enabled on my end, not sure if it's necessary for the link to work as expected.

You can find other special gmail labels [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/com/google/android/gm/contentprovider/GmailContract.Labels.LabelCanonicalNames).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could improve your answer by clarifying the conditions under which this would work.  For example, are you assuming the user has the "Priority Inbox" enabled?